# How to set PDO options?

Tags: php, pdo

I need to use silent PDO mode without any exceptions or errors so i do it like this:

```
$this->db = new PDO($db_config['dsn'], $db_config['username'], $db_config['password'], 
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT,
        PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
    )
);
```

But it still throws exception that i cant connect to db.

Answer (score 5):

> I need to use silent PDO mode

## Nope, you don't.

You are asking this question out of some false assumption. Instead of following it further, you have to rethink your premises, set PDO to Exception mode and then fix something else. Most likely - an error handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot connect to the database, PHP can't create a PDO object. You can't have a PDO object which is not connected to the database. You can't return anything but a valid object instance when using the `new` operator. Hence an exception is the only thing how the PDO constructor can fail here.

In other words, you can't silence an exception happening at construction time, that setting only applies to all later errors PDO may produce. You just have to `catch` it.